# Webpack / How to not bundle JS files in dev mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Basically, by default, the main point of webpack is to bundle every parsed JS files into a `bundle.js`.

In dev mode, I would like to have access to each JS separately.
I don't want them to be bundled in one file.

Is there a way to prevent webpack to concat files into `bundle.js` in dev mode?

I would like to see `A.js`, `B.js`, `C.js` when I open the source code of the page in dev mode, and not `bundle.js` that gathers them.

Comment: If the bundle is done correctly, Chrome will tell you what file you're in, even if you're in the bundle.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I noticed one hour ago. However, Firefox doesn't show those files like Chrome does (although sourcemaps are enabled).

Comment: Firefox has this problem for a long time - in our team we decided to stop using Firefox for this purpose.

Comment: @Everettss Oh ok :) Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that pops out of my head is that you can configure webpack's entry and output properties. By doing so, you are telling webpack to treat each entry separately and it will give you output files with the names of the 'key' in the entry object. See below for example:

```
// webpack.dev.js

entry: {
  A: 'src/js/A.js',
  B: 'src/js/B.js',
  C: 'src/js/C.js'
},

output: {
 path: 'dist',
 filename: '[name].js'
}
```

This will produce A.js, B.js and C.js.

More information from the documentation here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry